# Getting the name of the controller and action method in the view in ASP.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Is there a way in a view in ASP.Net MVC to get the names of the controller and actien method that are using the view?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Try this:

```
<%= ViewContext.RouteData.Values["Controller"] %>
<%= ViewContext.RouteData.Values["Action"] %>
```

Comment: Those names will reflect the casing of request url. What you do with them should not be case-sensitive. (I fell in that trap.)

Answer (score 5):

```
<%= ViewContext.RouteData.Values["Controller"] %>
<%= ViewContext.RouteData.Values["Action"] %>
```

Be aware that if along the way, your routing has passed through a redirect of some kind, then the those values will still refer to the original requested controller/action, not the "current" one.

So if a request to "/Home/Index" performs a redirect to "/Admin/Settings", then the above values will be "Home" and "Index" respectively and *not* "Admin" and "Settings" as perhaps may be expected or desired.