# ascx MVC controller need to know the calling Controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have an MVC View User Control and from with Controller I would like to find out what the name of the controller that the MVC View User Control has been called from.

Hope that makes sense?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1083774/getting-the-name-of-the-controller-and-action-method-in-the-view-in-asp-net-mvc OR http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1116294/better-way-to-find-controller-name-from-masterpage-view-in-asp-net-mvc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it :

```
<%=ViewContext.RouteData.Values["controller"] %>
```