# ASP.Net MVC Reading Action Parameter/ Route Info in a RenderPartial

Tags: asp.net-mvc

In my MVC app I have one action available on a public side so everything looks like http://www.domain.com/pagename

When it goes to the action method of my WebPageController it finds it in the DB by pagename and renders the View.

In the View I do a database call to a foreign key table called WebPageContent. For each WebPageContent I do a RenderPartial(WebPageContentItem.ControlType)

This works for the most part, I now have a need to have http://www.domain.com/pagename/idofsomething

I have made the changes relevant and the Controller is firing it. What I want to do is if the ID is passed to the Controller I need to get it to my RenderPartial call. I have got it working by setting the ID via ViewData but didn't know if that was the best approach?

Controller->ViewData->View->RenderPartial("Name",Model,ViewData)

In the actual UserControl can you read the action parameter or get it from ViewContext or similar?

In my RenderPartial I can then make a DB call to find the relevant item by the passed ID and then render relevant HTML from the DB object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<% var id = ViewContext.RouteData.Values["Id"]; %>
```

[SO - Getting the name of the controller and action method in the view in ASP.Net MVC ...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1083774/getting-the-name-of-the-controller-and-action-method-in-the-view-in-asp-net-mvc)