# Get ControllerName and ActionName and populate the ViewData in Master Page?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, master-pages

I've a `SuperController` which will be inherited from all the controllers. In the constructor I'm trying to populate the ViewData *using* the ControllerName and the ActionName.

I'm not going to pass the ControllerName and the ActionName as the ViewData. I've a method that needs the ControllerName and the ActionName and I need to pass the return value of the method as the ViewData.

How can I do that?

Comment: for getting action ,controller names take look at this http://stackoverflow.com/a/31749391/4293929

Answer (score 62):

Don't use `ViewData`. Use this in your Site.Master instead:

```
<%= ViewContext.RouteData.Values["Controller"] %>
<%= ViewContext.RouteData.Values["Action"] %>
```

[SO - Getting the name of the controller and action method in the view in ASP.Net MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1083774/getting-the-name-of-the-controller-and-action-method-in-the-view-in-asp-net-mvc)

Comment: Those names will reflect the casing of request url. What you do with them should not be case-sensitive. (I fell in that trap.)

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
RouteData.Values.First().Value.ToString()
```

Comment: If you use custom routing (e.g `language/controller/action`) `controller` may not be the first entry.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that I'm reading your post correctly, and you're not trying to access the controller/action names in the view, but INSTEAD trying to do something with them, and put the result into the viewdata:

You can't do it in the constructor because the context hasn't been created yet. You need to override the Initialize method:

```
protected override void Initialize(System.Web.Routing.RequestContext requestContext)
    {
        base.Initialize(requestContext);

        //here the routedata is available
        ViewData["controller_name"] = (ControllerContext.RouteData.Values["Controller"];
    }
```

(Note that you could pass in just the ControllerContext.RouteData to your function and let it pick the values it needs.)

Answer (score 1):

I needed to get at these alot from views, and I hit it from a slightly different angle--I wrote a few extension methods to HtmlHelper to give the current ControllerName and ActionName. A bit easier to handle as you don't need to worry about diving into the ViewData[] bag or injecting stuff at appropriate places.

Comment: I would think such extension methods would be better suited for UrlHelper, rather than HtmlHelper. Those two values really have nothing to do with HTML.

Comment: Good point--I think the implementation might have even got refactored that way. Theory is roughly the same in either case--pull it out rather than push it in.