# EF - Require either of two fields?

Tags: entity-framework, data-annotations

Is there a way to do what this question is doing
([Either Or Required Validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9560227/either-or-required-validation))
but instead of applying it on the entire class, I only want to apply the validation on two specific fields within the class.

For example

```
public class FooModel {

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public decimal Cost { get; set; }

    public int Bar1 { get; set; }

    public float Bar2 { get; set; }
}
```

I only want to constrain Bar1 and Bar2 to be an either/or requirement. They cannot both be null. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can add server side validation by implementing `IValidatableObject`

```
public class FooModel: IValidatableObject
{

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public decimal Cost { get; set; }

    public int Bar1 { get; set; }

    public float Bar2 { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        if (Bar1 == null && Bar2 == null)
            yield return new ValidationResult("Either Bar1 or Bar2  must be specified");
    }
}
```

Reference:

[Using IValidatableObject with POCOs for More Complex Validations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/data/gg193959.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I do not think you can do that by code first! I think you can do that by [validation](http://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2012/04/01/integrating-validation-with-the-entity-framework.aspx) or by used stored procedure / function  which be triggered by the inserting in the FooModel.
[EF to AFTER INSERT Trigger](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/aed080f9-e590-476e-9921-ca749fa3b2c9/alternative-to-after-insert-trigger?forum=adodotnetentityframework)