# In MVC3, how to get the current action name?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, httpcontext

Is there a way to use HttpContext or the View context to get the current action name?

I can get the controller name using

```
    var routeValues = HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values;

    if (routeValues != null) 
    {
        if (routeValues.ContainsKey("controller"))
        {
            controllerName = HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [ASP.NET MVC4: Get controller and action name from within controller?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18248547/asp-net-mvc4-get-controller-and-action-name-from-within-controller)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
var routeValues = HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values;
if (routeValues != null) 
{
    if (routeValues.ContainsKey("action"))
    {
        var actionName = routeValues["action"].ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the simplification, @PeterB!

Answer (score 0):

```
ViewContext.RouteData.Values["action"]
```

As far as I know, ViewContext.RouteData.Values will never be null and will always have the keys "controller" and "action". Please correct me if I am wrong.