# Null object cannot be converted to a value type exception is thrown inside ProcessRequest Method

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, httphandler, httpcontext

I am able to get the CurrentSideId, I can say anywhere through the application. I have a class called MainClass. It has static `CurrentSideId` property. `MainClass.CurrentSiteId` returns the `SiteId` requested.

```
public class MainClass{
   public static int CurrentSiteId
   {
      get { return HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["CurrentSiteId"].To<int>(); }
      set {..}
   }
}
```

But, when it comes to `ProcessRequest` method of the `HttpHandler`, `CurrentSiteId` throws an exception of type `System.InvalidCastException`: `Null object cannot be converted to a value type.`

```
public class MyRouteHandler : MvcRouteHandler
{
    protected override IHttpHandler GetHttpHandler(RequestContext requestContext)
    {
        return new MyHttpHandler();
    }
}
public class MyHttpHandler : IHttpHandler
{
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        var siteId = MainClass.CurrentSiteId;
    }
}
```

What would be the resolution?

Comment: What isn't clear about the error message? `Values` returns `null` because the key doesn't exist, hence it returns `null`, which you try to convert to an `int`.

Comment: How can I get the siteid inside the HttpHandler then?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to access it via `context` providing the route value is passed in:

```
Convert.ToInt16(context.Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["CurrentSiteId"]);
```

**Update**

Try the following:

```
public class MyHttpHandler : IHttpHandler
{
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        var siteId = Convert.ToInt16(context.Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["CurrentSiteId"]);
    }
}
```

Comment: I have already tried. There is no `To` extension for `Values["CurrentSiteId"]`.

Comment: @Jude I think you must either include the namespace for the extension method. If you go to definition of the `To<int>` method you will see that or use the above. I changed it to use `Convert.ToInt16` instead.

Comment: This only gives me the Controller Name and the Action Name. There seems no "CurrentSiteId" key.

Comment: @Jude The calling application must not be passing it across, what is calling it?

Comment: Edited the question. Added RouteHandler. Does this answer your question?

Comment: @Jude try the update just to see if you can get it outside of the class

Answer (score 0):

you should check that the value is not null before casting it
a good sample can be found here: [In MVC3, how to get the current action name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20626860/in-mvc3-how-to-get-the-current-action-name)
(replace action with the method you want to call)