# Web Api 2 Post - UrlHelper.Link must not return null

Tags: asp.net-web-api2

I have a basic web API 2 setup with some basic routing.

Below is the default route and post for inserts. When I call the post the record is created perfectly in the database but the "CreatedAtRoute" call returns a 500 error stating:

> ExceptionMessage: "UrlHelper.Link must not return null."
>   ExceptionType: "System.InvalidOperationException"

Why would I receive this error?

```
[RoutePrefix("api/casenotes")]
    public class CasenoteController : ApiController...



// POST api/Casenote
[Route("")]
[ResponseType(typeof(client_admission_casenote))]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Postclient_admission_casenote   (client_admission_casenote client_admission_casenote)
{

  Request.GetRequestContext().IncludeErrorDetail = true;

  if (!ModelState.IsValid)
  {
      return BadRequest(ModelState);
  }

  db.client_admission_casenote.Add(client_admission_casenote);
  await db.SaveChangesAsync();

  return CreatedAtRoute("DefaultApi", new { id = client_admission_casenote.casenote_id }, client_admission_casenote);
    }
```

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Since you are using attribute routing.. you have to name your route.. i.e.
    [Route("api/books/{id}", Name="GetBookById")]

and the use the route name on your url.link() call

see details here.. http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2#route-names

Comment: Thanks Ronnel, this should do the trick from the info but I still get the error.  // GET api/Casenote/5
        [Route("{casenoteId}/detail", Name="GetSingleCasenote")]
        [ResponseType(typeof(client_admission_casenote))] and then use the name in post: return CreatedAtRoute("GetSingleCasenote", new { id = client_admission_casenote.casenote_id }, client_admission_casenote);
        }

Comment: Ah, it's because I changed the default "id" value to "casenoteId".  I had to alter to : CreatedAtRoute("GetSingleCasenote", new { casenoteId = client_admission_casenote.casenote_id }, client_admission_casenote); }   Thank you much Ronnel!!!

Comment: As always, a right answer with a working explanation link is awesome!

Comment: This seems to work only with simple routes. I have a route with several ids and it still returns null.

Comment: @OlivierMATROT, did you ever figure this out? I'm having the same problem.

Comment: @Anov Sorry, I do not remember