# Get page name only using Request MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, head, rel, alternate

I want to add alternate tag for multiple lang. website, previous developer had added the alternate url using the below code:

```
 <link rel="alternate" href="@Request.Url.Scheme://@Request.Url.Authority/us/@Request.RawUrl.Remove(0,1).Replace("/us","")" hreflang="es-us" />
```

it was done only for one lang. Now I am facing problem to get the page only, rawurl is returning the "/us/folder/pagename" but I want "/folder/pagename". is there any way by which I can achieve this?

It is on html side, i don't want to get it on code level and pass to view. i am asking if there is any way by which i can get in view only.

Comment: @PaulZahra, how could it be the duplicate of this, have read the question carefully. ?

Comment: You are 'correct' in a way... so it's not the page name that you want... as you say in the title... it's the controller and view name ?

Comment: in mvc page name = actionname

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get controller and action name from within controller?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18248547/get-controller-and-action-name-from-within-controller)