# How to hide specific element on page from _Layout.cshtml page

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I work on mvc 5 project.

On my `_Layout.cshtml` I have html element named `id="topBar"` this element displayed in each page.

But I have page named About.cshtml I don't want this page to display only element `id="topBar"` all other html elements in `_Layout.cshtml` I want them to be displayed normal in `About.cshtml`.

Any idea how can achieve described appearance above?

Comment: Can you not use `jQuery` to achieve this?

Comment: `@if (ViewContext.RouteData.Values["action"].ToString() != "About")  { ... }`

Answer (score 7):

One simple way of achieving this (without javascript), is to set a value in `ViewBag` inside your about `Action` and use it in layout like this:

**_Layout.cshtml**

```
@if (ViewBag.ShowTopBar ?? false)
{
    <div id="topBar">

    </div>
}
```

Action inside your **Controller**:

```
public class MyAwesomeController : Controller
{

    public ActionResult About()
    {
        ViewBag.ShowTopBar = true;
        return View();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

There are two options:

#### 1. Add an ID to every `body` element

You could add an `ID` to the body of each of your pages that contains for example the Controller and Action name and then add a CSS rule to hide the topBar element on the about page.

First, let's create two string variables for the controller and action name. Do this in your _Layout.cshtml:

```
@{
    string controller = ViewContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString();
    string action = ViewContext.RouteData.Values["action"].ToString();
}
```

Next, add the ID to the body:

```
<body id="@controller-@action">
```

In your css, you can now add a rule to hide the topbar in the about page (assuming the controller is called HomeController):

```
#Home-About #topBar {display:none;}
```

You could also use an extension method to get the controller and action name. For example something [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26184534/106866).

#### 2. Use jQuery on the About page

You could add a Javascript on your about page and use jQuery to hide the topbar (I assume jQuery is already loaded):

```
<script>
   $("#topBar").hide();
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Easier way, just did that: style your page individually:

```
<style>
    #showcase {  display: none; }   
</style>
```

Put this on the page that you want to hide, showcase is my section id.   ;)