# Checking for an attribute in an action filter

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

In MVC 5, you can do something like this inside an `IActionFilter`, to check if an attribute has been declared on the the current action (or at controller scope)

```
public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
{
    // Stolen from System.Web.Mvc.AuthorizeAttribute
    var isAttributeDefined = filterContext.ActionDescriptor.IsDefined(typeof(CustomAttribute), true) ||
                             filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ControllerDescriptor.IsDefined(typeof(CustomAttribute), true);

}
```

So if your controller defines the attribute like so, this works.

```
[CustomAttribute]
public ActionResult Everything()
{ .. }
```

Is it possible to do the same in ASP.NET Core MVC (inside an `IActionFiler`)?

Comment: Keep in mind, there is no MVC6, just ASP.NET Core MVC 1.0, 1.1 and 2.0 preview ;)

Comment: Gah! I stand corrected!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Yes you can do it. Here is similar code for ASP.NET Core.

```
public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
{
    var controllerActionDescriptor = context.ActionDescriptor as ControllerActionDescriptor;
    if (controllerActionDescriptor != null)
    {
        var isDefined = controllerActionDescriptor.MethodInfo.GetCustomAttributes(inherit: true)
            .Any(a => a.GetType().Equals(typeof(CustomAttribute)));
    }
}
```

Comment: NOTE: this uses reflection. Can be slow! Don't use this answer, look here instead: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60602828/56621

Comment: @AlexfromJitbit a bit discorcerning the XML comment on context.ActionDescriptor.EndpointMetadata: "This API is meant for infrastructure and should not be used by application code."

Answer (score 7):

If you need to check the attribute, not only for a method but also for the whole controller in .NET Core, here is how I did it:

```
var controllerActionDescriptor = actionContext.ActionDescriptor as ControllerActionDescriptor;

if (controllerActionDescriptor != null)
{
    // Check if the attribute exists on the action method
    if (controllerActionDescriptor.MethodInfo?.GetCustomAttributes(inherit: true)?.Any(a => a.GetType().Equals(typeof(CustomAttribute))) ?? false)
        return true;

    // Check if the attribute exists on the controller
    if (controllerActionDescriptor.ControllerTypeInfo?.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(CustomAttribute), true)?.Any() ?? false)
        return true;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
if (context.Filters.Any(x => x.GetType() == typeof(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Authorization.AllowAnonymousFilter)))
            return;
```