# How to check if the called action has a specific attribute in ASP.Net Core?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, .net-core

I am trying to build my custom authorization `middle ware` in `ASP.Net Core`. Which checks if the called `action` (method in controller class) is tagged by `[Authorize]` attribute. I still do not have good ideas how can I implement that.

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
    app.Use((context, next) =>
    {
        // if (THE CALLED ACTION HAS [Authorize] attribute)
        //     DO SOMETHING...
        return next();
    });

    app.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute();     
}
```

Could some one give me any hint to implement the commented condition?

Comment: That early in pipeline the action has not been determined as yet so there is not even an action to check for attributes.

Comment: @Nkosi, ok so is it some how possible to get that working by implementing my own middle ware?

Comment: I would suggest reading up here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware?tabs=aspnetcore2x

Comment: @Nkosi, actually I have just finished reading it before asking, but I still have not got it yet, sorry. Could you give any related hint? So how does MVC with its build in identity knows that something is tagged with `[Authorize]` attribute, when it is called before using MVC? I appreciate any hint which helps me to implement that.

Comment: You should avoid trying to reinvent existing features. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity?tabs=visual-studio%2Caspnetcore2x

Comment: @Nkosi I am trying to avoid using Identity because it abstracts a lot of details (and adds some over head some where else). Understanding how I can implement it will be a good practice for me as well.

Comment: Understood. The problem is going through all of that is way too broad to answer on this site.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158363/discussion-between-mohammed-noureldin-and-nkosi).

Comment: OK during reading `ASP.Net Core MVC` source code on `Github`, I find a hint which looks a good place to start, the `filters` (an option of MVC middleware). I will read it and I will post my answer if I get anything useful.

Comment: filters are the way to go

Comment: For Authorization you don't need Identity. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/cookie?tabs=aspnetcore2x

Answer (score 1):

In general, if you need to check whether the action has an attribute, you need to use the action filter, not middleware.

Why? Cause action methods are part of MVC middleware and so action filters are. While standard middlewares don't know about MVC concept.

Comment: How to check if the current called action has XZY attribute inside using the filter? Could you post some lines code please?

Comment: @MohammedNoureldin look into SO [Checking for an attribute in an action filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44199347/checking-for-an-attribute-in-an-action-filter)

Comment: Ah perfect! Thank you!